# jquery increasing/decreasing element attribute on browser resize

Tags: jquery, increment

I have a div that I'd like to increase the marginTop in increments of 2 when the browser width is increasing and decreasing by increments of two while it's decreasing in width.  I'm not really sure how to do this, but it should be easy.  Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: use the [resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event

Comment: **What code have you tried so far?** These "make this thing for me" posts don't typically go over well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
// your code goes here
});
```